# Apple Mach-O linker error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386 Google Protobuf

Tags: c++, ios, protocol-buffers, xcode6.3, i386

I am trying to use Protobuf 2.6 with Xcode version 6.3. I've added the libprotobuf-lite.a to my Demo application and added the path to the Header files in the Header Search Paths., but I am getting this error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "google::protobuf::io::StringOutputStream::StringOutputStream(std::string*)",
>   referenced from:
>         attributes::MergePartialFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*)
>   in attributes.pb.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: Could you add some of your code to the question? And maybe the desired output?

Comment: I am using proto buf  in a big project to just send the ip addresses and port number from one side to another. But after adding those proto buff files (.h and .cc) I am getting the above mentioned compilation error.                               PS- i have added all the header paths and library properly.

Comment: Does the protobuf library include support for CPU Arch i386 (use `file` or `lipo` to find out)?

Comment: NO  i m working for armv7 armv7s

Comment: You are linking for i386 (see the error message), so the library needs to have support for it.

Comment: Yes, I know that. And i cannot change that code. Actually I want some work around for that. changing the code will take life time of my time. Hope you understand that.

Comment: @trojanfoe Is there any way ,so that i can do it for i386 ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using protobuf in *library form*.  When I've used it in the past I've simply pulled the protobuf source files into the project.  Problem solved.

Comment: @trojanfoe  which source files are you talking about ( .pb.h & .pb.cc)? I have dragged them to my project but ti make thrm work i need the libraries and the header files  which are present in the "include" folder of Protobuf  and for that purpose iam giving the path of those headers and library .

Comment: No I'm talking about all the protobuf source files (the ones in the library).

Comment: @trojanfoe I  try doing what you suggested but it did not work out for me.